# Setting dynamic height for <iframe> in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe, browser, safari

I am developing a web application using Spring MVC framework, in one of my modules I have implemented an `<iframe>` to display user posts and comments. Now my problem is the `<iframe>` height should be set dynamically based on the contents in the `<iframe>`. I am using the following JavaScript for this purpose. It works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer but not in Google Chrome and Safari. How to solve this problem?

```
function sizeFrame() {
  jQuery("#myframe", top.document).css({ height: 0 });
                        var iframe=document.getElementById('myframe');
                var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
                var the_height=0;
                 if (iframeWin.document.body) {
                 the_height = iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;
                }
               jQuery("#myframe", top.document).css({ height: the_height }); 
              }

             </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code to your java script function that solves your problem,

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
var is_safari=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1;
 if(is_chrome || is_safari)
{
jQuery("#myframe", top.document).css({ height: 0 }); 
var myframe = jQuery("#myframe");var innerDoc = (myframe.get(0).contentDocument) ? myframe.get(0).contentDocument : myframe.get(0).contentWindow.document;
var h;
if(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight)
 h=innerDoc.body.scrollHeight+35;
else
 h=innerDoc.documentElement.scrollHeight;
jQuery("#myframe", top.document).css({ height: h  }); 
}
```